# What is the right signature of constant comparator or method for subclasses?

Tags: java, generics

I have an abstract class looks like this.

```java
abstract class Some {

    int rank;
}
```

Now I want to define a static variable and/or method of comparing the `rank`.

```
static <T extends Some> Compartor<T> comparingRank() {
    return Comparator.compartingInt(Some::getRank);
}
```

```java
static final Compartor<Some> COMPARING_RANK
        = Compartor.comparingInt(Some::getRank);
```

My questions are...

- Should I use `<? super T>` for `comparingRank()` method?
- Should I use `<? super T>` for `COMPARING_RANK` field?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We generally don't encourage to use wildcards in the return type of the method, since that renders the method unusable. So, the first option is ruled out due to that.

The second variant of using a lower bound wildcard `? super T` is generally a good thing which makes your API much more flexible. But, in this particular scenario, the `comparingInt` declares that wildcard, leaving yours superfluous.

`static <T> Comparator<T> comparingInt(ToIntFunction<? super T> keyExtractor)`

Thus, in my opinion, you can keep it as it is without any modification. However, you may still use the wildcard where circumstances warrant.